# Xpath not working with selenium Web Driver

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

I have a problem triying to recognize a xpath from the following web page

http://smartchanneltech.com/top100canalti/

This is the element I want to recognize: https://i.stack.imgur.com/q1ccv.jpg

This is the xpath that I´m using:`/html/body/div/div/div[1]/h1/a`

This is the code I´m using:

```
public WebElement Empresa (WebDriver driver, int Iterator) {

    //WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);

    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div/div[1]/h1/a")));
    return driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div/div[1]/h1/a"));

    }
```

And, finally, this is the error log: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hRlPG.jpg

I tried just to `driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div/div[1]/h1/a"));` but is not working also.

Can you help me with this please?

Comment: It is inside a iframe. first switch to frame and try as given below in my answer.

Comment: I have added an answer for that. Please try to use it and let me know your feedback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look into the `HTML DOM` the `WebElement` is within an `<iframe>`. So we need to switch to the `<iframe>` first with proper `WebDriverWait` and then locate the `WebElement` as follows :

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.xpath("//iframe[@src='https://www.rise.global/display/top100-canalti/latest/embeddable/cut/stripes']")));
return driver.findElement(By.xpath("div[@class='lb-leaderboard-header']/h1/a[@class='lb-leaderboard-name']"));
```

Answer (score 1):

It is inside a iframe. First switch to the frame and try identifying it.

```
public WebElement Empresa (WebDriver driver, int Iterator) {
   driver.switchTo().frame(0);
   String xpath="/html/body/div/div/div[1]/h1/a";
   wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(xpath)));
   return driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath));
}
```

Comment: Works well! Thank you! Some questions:

1.- Seems like code is running faster than the load of the webpage, is any easy way to wait until elements of the display are syncronize?

2.- How dou you know that is in a Frame and what frame (number) is?

3.- How can switch back to the page?

Thank!

Comment: 1. webdriver wait is best way to wait. 2. If any one of the parent tag is iframe. You can say, it is inside iframe. 3. you can use driver.switchTo().defaultContent() to get back to the main html.

Answer (score 0):

I have update the method as below.
Please use this.

```
public WebElement Empresa (WebDriver driver, int Iterator) {

//WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.xpath("//iframe[@src='https://www.rise.global/display/top100-canalti/latest/embeddable/cut/stripes']")));

driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.tagName("iframe")));

WebElement elem = driver.findElement(By.className("lb-leaderboard-widget-wrapper"));
WebElement elemH1 = elem.findElement(By.tagName("h1"));
WebElement elemIWant = elem.findElement(By.tagName("a"));

System.out.println(elemIWant.getAttribute("innerHTML").toString());

return elemIWant;

}
```

let me know your feedback.

Comment: @Ivan Garrido can you please check my answer and let me know your feedback.